# How to access android data from blackberry native app?

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have an android app repackaged for blackberry 10. This app is published on Blackberry World. Now I want to replace this app with its native (Cascades) version. My problem is that all user persistent data got lost after upgrade.
Apparently I need to find a way to access persistent data stored via Android platform API:

```
public SharedPreferences getPreferences()
{
    return m_context.getSharedPreferences(m_containerName, 0);
}
```

Is there any way to access this data from Blackberry native app?  How to keep application data after upgrade from android repackaged app to blackberry native?